# Storing all directory names in variables

Tags: batch-file

How do I write a windows batch file that stores all of the folder names in a directory in individual variables?  I do not know how many folders will be in the directory at any given time.  I'm pretty sure that I need a for loop.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
    @ECHO OFF
    set /a c=1
    setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    for /d %%f in (c:\users\*) do echo.file %%f
    for /d %%A in (c:\users\*) do (set "var!c!=%%A")
    ECHO.%var!c!%
```

Comment: What environment are you working in?

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: What do you means stores in individual variables. What are you trying to accomplish with this project?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps What you can do is write the output of command

```
dir /AD
```

in some file called as folders.txt then can do operations on number of folders by storing them into any an array variable , something like this.

```
for %%G in (folders.txt) do (
set /a count+=1
call :exec1 %%~nG
echo %%~nG
)
goto :continue1

:exec1
echo %count%
set mapArray[%count%]=%1
goto :end

:continue1
:end
```

Comment: Firstly, a file can be read with a `FOR /F` loop, but not with a `FOR` one. Secondly, you can use a `FOR /F` loop to read the output of `DIR /AD` *directly*, without storing it to a file. Thirdly, you can use a `FOR /D` loop to iterate over directory names (i.e. it can be used *instead* of reading the output of `DIR /AD`). Other than that, the method you are using is basically what I would use too. Except I don't know why I would want to do such a thing to begin with. :) And one more little note: you can use `GOTO :EOF` to jump to the end of the script without declaring the `:EOF` explicitly.